# How to get most recent message from top posted email message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, email

I am working on an application with a requirement for mail inbox type functionality.

We get email content by calling a web service. The web service provides email in [Top posting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posting_style#Top-posting) format like the content shown below.

I am using Asp.net MVC3 and C# 4.0

```
No problem.  6pm it is then.
Jim 
-------- Original Message --------
From: Danny 
Sent: Tuesday, October 16, 2007 10:01 AM
To: Jim 
Subject: RE: Job
Whoa!  Hold on.  I have a job scheduled at 5:30 which mails out
a report to key tech staff.  Could you please push it back an hour?
Danny
-------- Original Message --------
From: Jim 
Sent: Tuesday, October 16, 2007 9:40 AM
To: Danny 
Subject: Job
I'm going to suspend the mail service for approx. thirty
minutes tonight, starting at 5pm, to install some updates
and important fixes.
Jim
```

My question is what's the best and efficient way to parse this format so that I can get list of all the messages and the most recent message that is at the top?

Comment: Do you have access to the source code behind the message, or just plain text? It may not be safe enough to say that "-------- Original Message --------" is the one absolute way to split up messages.

Comment: I don't have access to the source code I got a response from the webservice in the above format and there are no other method exposed by the webservice

Comment: Is the web service something that can be public knowledge? i.e. can we get documentation for it, or a name?

Comment: No :) actually it's a bank application and we have only this much of information :(

Comment: Shoot. I really think you need the content dividers from the message source code, otherwise you have to guess what strings differentiate between messages in a chain. Maybe someone can come up with something else.

Comment: I would start from the top and keep reading characters into a buffer until you are sure the bottom bounds have been met (worst case, you capture too much, rather than cutting off the message). You can look for multiple things, e.g. "------ Original", "From: ", email addresses, etc. and if enough of those are reached in the correct sequence, you can assume that you've read in the first post.

Comment: A regex could also do this, although it would be complicated/impossible if you wanted to make a fuzzy decision (e.g. "I've reached 'from: ' and an email address, but I never saw the '------ Original Message ------' divider. 2 out of 3 is sufficient".